# filterBy (primefaces 3.2) doesn't work with date

Tags: jsf-2

am usign jsf 2.0 + primefaces 3.2. i have a problem with filterBy when the data is a date but it works with other types of data.

```
<p:column sortBy="#{item.dateNaissance}" filterBy="#{item.dateNaissance}">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListEtudiantTitle_dateNaissance}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.dateNaissance}">
                                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
                            </h:outputText>
                        </p:column>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

default filtering doesn't work for date field, though you can use advanced filtering option and provide a filter server side method which does the filtering from the data set for you.

Basically you will specify your metho on key up event and filter record as per your need, default assumes everything to be String.